# iOS - textview cursor is displaced

Tags: ios, uitextview

As you can see in the image above the cursor looks displaced when I mark scroll as disable.
The textview It's inside of stackview.
How can I solved?

[image]

Comment: is using UITextField in palce of UITextView is option for you?

Comment: Are you doing this on a simulator?

Comment: @SatishMavani I need multiline.

Comment: @Rikh tested on simulator and iphone 5s and 6s

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug.
I have the **scrollable property** as disable and a **height constraint**.
I don't need a height constraint if I want the uitextview grow how much as it's content automatically.